# ⌊3/x⌋ + ⌊4/x⌋ = 5

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Q. Find domain: $\lfloor \dfrac3x \rfloor + \lfloor \dfrac4x \rfloor = 5$

My approach:

$\dfrac3x - 1 ≤ \lfloor \dfrac3x \rfloor ≤ \dfrac3x$

$\dfrac4x - 1 ≤ \lfloor \dfrac4x \rfloor ≤ \dfrac4x$

Adding them,

$\dfrac7x - 2 ≤ \lfloor \dfrac3x \rfloor + \lfloor \dfrac4x \rfloor ≤ \dfrac7x$

$\dfrac7x - 2 ≤ 5 ≤ \dfrac7x$

$x \in (1, \frac75]$

Comment: You're not done yet. You've found **a** constraint. You need to check whether that's **all** the constraint. I suspect it isn't.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137417/find-range-of-x-satisfying-left-lfloor-frac3x-right-rfloor-left-lf

Comment: Thanks for the link :) I got it. Is there any systematic way to search for such questions?

Comment: Solution should be $1<x<4/3$